# I get an error in useRouteQuery and Vitest. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, vuejs3, vitest

When testing the composite function using Vitest, I get the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZKIA.jpg)

in the function I simply declare
const redirectTo = useRouteQuery("redirectTo");

I would like to solve the problem with useRouteQuery

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Error: Invalid value used as weak map key